# Excel display each row 10 times then move on to next row?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm sure there are duplicate questions/answers for this, but I'm not sure how to word it so I can find what I need...

I have a list of unique items (22000+ rows), I have a second list of 10 locations. I am trying to create a 3rd list where each unique item is displayed beside each of my 10 locations. This seems like it should be very simple, but when I drag-fill Excel is jumping by 10 rows (A2 > A12 > A22 > etc...) instead of 1 at a time (A2 > A3 > A4 > etc...). Here is an example of how I thought this should pull (i'll just use 3 locations for my example, but I actually have 10):

| Item | Location |
| --- | --- |
| Items!$A2 | Locations!$B$2 |
| Items!$A2 | Locations!$B$3 |
| Items!$A2 | Locations!$B$4 |
| Items!$A3 | Locations!$B$2 |
| Items!$A3 | Locations!$B$3 |
| Items!$A3 | Locations!$B$4 |
| Items!$A4 | Locations!$B$2 |
| Items!$A4 | Locations!$B$3 |
| Items!$A4 | Locations!$B$4 |

I apologize for asking a question I'm sure many others have asked.

Comment: You can something like this `=OFFSET($A$2;ROW()/10;0)`

Comment: Put them in a matrix and use the `=Tocol()` function (if available).

Comment: @Blackcat, this solution is very close to what I need, I'm seeing the first item is only displaying 8 while all others are displaying 10?

Comment: This is because  row() gives the actual row number. Subtract from that the fow value where you start from. `(Row()-x)/10`

Comment: @Blackcat, this worked!

Comment: `=INDEX(Items!A:A,SEQUENCE(22000,,2,1/10))` and `=INDEX(Items!B:B,MOD(SEQUENCE(22000,,0),10)+2)` ?